# Why QGIS removes the XYZ Tile Connection Referer?

Tags: qgis, tiles, xyz, connection, heading

In QGIS when i make a XYZ Tile connection with a referer, QGIS removes the referer! Why?

See animated gif:

[image]

Comment: Mine works fine; which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: QGIS 3.30, Which version do you use?

Comment: 3.28, which is the current "long term release". You may have found a recently-introduced bug, but in any case unless you have a good reason to be using 3.30 I'd recommend sticking to 3.28 which is intended to be more stable.